# 30-40% battery drain at night

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, battery, battery-life, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I am using unlocked Samsung Galaxy S5 G900F model for 1 year.
It working fine. But for 3-4 months I cannot keep my phone on overnight.
It drains battery to 30%-40%. I have tried all possible solution like:

1. kept brightness to minimum
2. WiFi, mobile data, Bluetooth, GPS kept off
3. stopped unwanted services like FB, S finder, etc from App manager.

I mean all possible options.

It shows that Phone radio and network are draining my batter (as shown in attached images)
Also how can screen brightness drain battery when kept idle screen locked mode overnight? (as shown in attached images)
Please Help.
I have attached screenshots when I found 69% battery remaining in the morning (kept at 100% at night)

Note:

1. During day battery performs normally even with WiFi and data
2. Even when kept in ultra power saving mode overnight it drains around 20% battery

[image: Screenshot1]
[image: Screenshot2]
[image: Screenshot3]
[image: Screenshot4]
[image: Screenshot5]

<sub>Screenshots - Battery Info(Click to enlarge images)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

That's a known bug in android where there is no real solution for, you live in a zone with bad reception or just in between antennas.
Possible solution are: moving. Or, set your phone to **2G** networks only, certainly at night. I ALWAYS put my phone on flightmode at night...

if you are rooted you can use an app for that: 2G 3G 4G switch

I read the bug is even still there in the current beta version of Android M (6.0).
I had the problem for a while but then it suddenly went away... maybe antenna transmission had slightly changed by my provider.

Comment: It's not only about network. I've two devices from different OEMs but with same network. One works fine on 3G without being a battery hogger while the other keeps draining the battery by trying to switch from 2G to 3G and vice-versa (when selected WCDMA mode only). The issue in my case is related to modem. I flashed my  modem and the drain slowed down but is still there.

Comment: Put your phone into airplane mode at night, otherwise it will kill itself looking for signal.

Comment: Another of probably many other causes: how cold does it get at night? I find when camping unless I keep phone warm it drains very quickly.